# Can't seem to shorten decimal numbers of my Pandas column

Tags: pandas, decimal

So I have a df column which I created by taking an average of three other columns

`df['Avg_Grade'] = df.loc[:,'G1':'G3'].mean(axis =1)`

The series looks like this (just a sample)

```
   Avg_Grade  
0   5.666667  
1   5.333333  
2   8.333333  
3  14.666667  
4   8.666667
```

I'm trying to truncate the output to show something like

```
 0   5.67 (5.66 is also fine)
 1   5.33  
 2   8.33  
 3   14.67  
 4   8.67
```

I've played around with the module`Decimal` with the following code, but I'm getting an error.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 4


df['Avg_Grade'] = Decimal(df.loc[:,'G1':'G3'].mean(axis =1))


 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#409>", line 1, in <module>
    df['Avg_Grade'] = Decimal(df.loc[:,'G1':'G3'].mean(axis =1))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 657, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)
TypeError: Cannot convert 0       5.666667
```

Comment: try `df.Avg_Grade.round(2)`

Comment: Thanks this seems to work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, but they won't work in all situations.

Here's an example dataframe:

```
In [1]:
df = pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3), columns=['G1','G2','G3'])
df['Avg_Grade'] = df.loc[:,'G1':'G3'].mean(axis =1)
df

Out [1]:
         G1        G2        G3  Avg_Grade
0  9.843159  4.155922  9.652694   7.883925
1  2.108822  9.347634  9.271351   6.909269
2  2.681108  3.071449  0.387151   2.046569
3  4.017461  9.464408  0.395482   4.625783
```

**1. Use a global pandas setting**

All floats will be displayed with two decimals. You can use either of the following:

```
pd.options.display.precision = 2
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)

In [3]: df

Out[3]:
     G1    G2    G3  Avg_Grade
0  9.84  4.16  9.65       7.88
1  2.11  9.35  9.27       6.91
2  2.68  3.07  0.39       2.05
3  4.02  9.46  0.40       4.63
```

**2. Use a global setting within a `with` statement.**

All floats displayed within the with statement will display with two decimals, but after it will revert to the regular value (default:6)

```
 In [4]: with pd.option_context('display.precision', 2):
             print(df)
 Out[4]:
     G1    G2    G3  Avg_Grade
0  9.84  4.16  9.65       7.88
1  2.11  9.35  9.27       6.91
2  2.68  3.07  0.39       2.05
3  4.02  9.46  0.40       4.63
```

Once you're outside of the with statement:

```
In [5]: print(df['Avg_Grade'])
0    7.883925
1    6.909269
2    2.046569
3    4.625783
Name: Avg_Grade, dtype: float64

print(df['Avg_Grade'])
```

**3. Using an HTML styler.**

This requires you run your code in a Jupyter Notebook.

```
df.style.set_precision(3)
```

**4. Using `round()`**

If you want to display something, you can also use something like:

```
df.round(2)
df['Avg_Grade'].round(2)
```

**5. Creating another dataframe or modifying in place**

**This way will let you customize the precision column by column**, but the underlying data is changed, so you might want to do that on a copy.

```
# Create a copy so we don't mess up the original df
df_print = df.copy()

# Round down some numbers
df_print['Avg_Grade'] = df_print['Avg_Grade'].round(2)
df_print['G1'] = df_print['Avg_Grade'].round(4)

# Add more decimals: need to switch that to a string representation
df_print['G3'] = df_print['G3'].map(lambda x: "{:,.10f}".format(x))

# display
df_print

     G1        G2            G3  Avg_Grade
0  7.88  4.155922  9.6526935480       7.88
1  6.91  9.347634  9.2713506079       6.91
2  2.05  3.071449  0.3871511232       2.05
3  4.63  9.464408  0.3954815519       4.63
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for taking out the time to explain all the methods. I'm going to print this out   =)

Comment: Or you could just bookmark it and save a tree! ;)
Note that it might not be "all the methods" (many many ways to skin a cat in pandas), but 5 is a good start!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to round values inside columns you can just change global display settings:

```py
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
```

It also works for [styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)